# How svelte-kit build for staging env?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to build a svelte app using svelte-kit for staging environments. I did not find a suitable command to take `.env.staging` as its configs.

When I execute `svelte-kit build` it always takes `.env.production`

Please helps me with how to build for staging env.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/512#issuecomment-656547187 - check this answer (and topic), there are some workarounds.

Copy of the answer:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:dev": "APP_ENV=development vite build",
    "build:prod": "APP_ENV=production vite build",
}
```

In your vite.config.js, now you can manipulate it:

```
const mode = process.env.APP_ENV // This now exists.

module.exports = {
  mode: mode, // This will set the mode, to avoid confusions.
}
```

Also another github issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1258

Comment: This is no longer working, at least for me. Do you know if there's a newer way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

David's answer worked for me until `"@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0"`. Now I use:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "stage": "vite build --mode staging",
  "prod": "vite build --mode production",
  ...
```

via `npm run stage` to build for staging and `npm run prod` to build for production. These commands map to `.env.stage` and `.env.production` files at the root of the project.

Answer (score 2):

In recent SvelteKit version - e.g. `1.0.0-next.370` - the build scripts `svelte-kit` have been replaced by the direct usage of `vite`

used to be:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
    "build": "svelte-kit build",
```

is now:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
```

Therefore it is possible to use Vite environment configuration files ([documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes)).

For example, I you would like to create an `.env.staging` file that contains your staging variables, you could add a following script to your `package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "staging": "npm run dev -- --mode staging"
```

which can be run in the command line with the corresponding target

```
> npm run staging
```

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting the production environment variables. I tried `npm run build -- --mode development`. Any idea if I'm missing something?

Comment: Not sure, according [vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes), `vite build --mode staging` should do.

Comment: Yeah, weird, I created an issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8323 Thanks for your help!